# Is it possible to have a RegionPlot of $y$ and $x^3$ for those values of $x$ and $y$ which satisfy $ \sin (x y) > 0$?

Tags: plotting

I have this function $\sin (x y)$ and want to check where it is positive for $0<x<8$ and $0<y<5$. I use  `RegionPlot` as

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x y] > 0, {y, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 8}, FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}]
```

and this is the result

[image]

**Now, my question is:**

Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give me a  `RegionPlot` in which the $y$ axis is the same as the above plot, but the vertical axis is the third power of those $x$ in the above plot? In other words, is it possible to have a  `RegionPlot` of $y$ and $x^3$ for those values of $x$ and $y$ which satisfy this condition $  \sin (x y) > 0$?

Comment: How about `RegionPlot[Sin[t^(1/3) y] > 0, {y, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 81}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"y", "x^3"}]`?

Comment: But this works. It does not suit you.

Comment: @user64494 Apology and thanks, it seems that this is indeed the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean, i.e. a literal change of the tick values?

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x y] > 0, {y, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 8}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"y", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)"},
  FrameTicks -> {
    {{#, #^3} & /@ Range[-2, 10, 2], None},
    {Automatic, None}
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: @charmin Not sure about the inverted axis: `RegionPlot` does not work well with `ScalingFunctions`, which would be the easiest way to achieve that. The Range expression simply generates some numbers in the same range and with the same pitch as the original ticks in your original plot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to draw
$$\{(y,t) : t=x^3,\sin(xy)>0\}$$
That is just
$$ \{ (y,t) : \sin(t^{1/3}y)>0 \}$$

```
RegionPlot[Sin[t^(1/3)*y] > 0 , {y, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 8}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image]

And you can also do this by `ScalingFunctions` in `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x*y], {y, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 8}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> {Gray, Green}, FrameLabel -> {y, x}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{# &, # &}, {# &, #^(1/3) &}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and [`TransformedRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) as follows:

```
implicitpregion = ImplicitRegion[{Sin[x y] > 0}, {y, x}];

transformedregion = TransformedRegion[implicitpregion, ({#[[1]], #[[2]]^3} &)];
```

Use with `RegionPlot` with desired settings for `PlotRange`:

```
Row[{RegionPlot[implicitpregion, ImageSize -> 250, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8}}], 
   RegionPlot[transformedregion, ImageSize -> 250, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8}}]
   RegionPlot[transformedregion, ImageSize -> 250, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8^3}}]}, 
 Spacer[15]]
```

[image]